# Extract cert, private key and cert chain from this string using python regex

Tags: python, regex, certificate

I have this string (obviously i cut some lines from all 3 not to expose myself).
I want python to extract from it:

Intermediate-cert

Key

Public-cert

And write them to 3 separate files named as above.

I am trying to use this regex, but it is taking all of them together.

match1 = re.findall(r"Intermediate cert((.|\n)*)(-----END CERTIFICATE-----)",strsecret,re.MULTILINE)

```
    (GetSecretResult){
Errors = ""
Secret =
  (Secret){
     Name = "new cert"
     Items =
        (ArrayOfSecretItem){
           SecretItem[] =
              (SecretItem){
                 Value = "new cert"
                 Id = 1470
                 FieldId = 334
                 FieldName = "E-Mail"
                 IsFile = False
                 IsNotes = False
                 IsPassword = False
                 FieldDisplayName = "E-Mail"
              },
              (SecretItem){
                 Value = "no password"
                 Id = 1471
                 FieldId = 335
                 FieldName = "Password"
                 IsFile = False
                 IsNotes = False
                 IsPassword = True
                 FieldDisplayName = "Password"
              },
              (SecretItem){
                 Value = None
                 Id = 1472
                 FieldId = 336
                 FieldName = "Account ID"
                 IsFile = False
                 IsNotes = False
                 IsPassword = False
                 FieldDisplayName = "Account ID"
              },
              (SecretItem){
                 Value = None
                 Id = 1473
                 FieldId = 337
                 FieldName = "Sign-in Link"
                 IsFile = False
                 IsNotes = False
                 IsPassword = False
                 FieldDisplayName = "Sign-in Link"
              },
              (SecretItem){
                 Value = "Intermediate cert

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Key

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAwvZA860zwvDZhCQNFwB0Jzg5EQ268/1Hzf3w4RJJKv5gi/v3
7pXEOJ10bpasoL3+8kIIYhDRQ83V0svf11qf3eJy0prp/mBjSGTcy5yJdixMfyAZ
AQ9/fPYkdt91leCm0JW9DnlWyIp0vwHV1Hu1vHyYtZ7yyE//yZHTLsyRFXPJ9bP6
JEL/w6HIL4thHqt5cEExmTmlMmEYD+6CTBGxwy3dqi+0yqMjk7yR1+pNql7oUrO2
7jj/QYAcjp34jysYBkyiMC4OQA8OXwEQt0uH3IPULhu0nWr5xD+wNlJo8VE4uQep
aEbjuAoSW/wZQDn/8qQIhsrg1jc+L280Qh1PY1udmMTZhUrijkO1
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Public cert

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGKDCCBRCgAwIBAgIQDPM2aqTO5b54DhFedbNBbjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBc
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMRswGQYDVQQDExJUaGF3dGUgUlNBIENBIDIwMTgwHhcN
MTgwOTEyMDAwMDAwWhcNMTkxMTE3MTIwMDAwWjCBmTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxETAP
BgNVBAgTCFZpcmdpbmlhMRcwFQYDVQQHEw5UeXNvbidzIENvcm5lcjEcMBoGA1UE
ChMTTWljcm9TdHJhdGVneSwgSW5jLjEcMBoGA1UECxMTSW5mb3JtYXRpb24gU3lz
vo3WIr8Ja9XFqfg/GHzMYwjYG/jkzmdEV4fke3LkTaYFtblAvE3hU4UXZWnT1y4W
vXySQ7BvTxgxRTUIWRN+qPJK6UsmNU4HizBjktCjxq6xqBdE55jsda7hqDg=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"
                 Id = 147274
                 FieldId = 366
                 FieldName = "Notes"
                 IsFile = False
                 IsNotes = True
                 IsPassword = False
                 FieldDisplayName = "Notes"
              },
        }
     Id = 31346
     SecretTypeId = 6055
     FolderId = 586
     IsWebLauncher = False
     Active = True
     CheckOutMinutesRemaining = None
     IsCheckedOut = None
     CheckOutUserDisplayName = None
     CheckOutUserId = None
     IsOutOfSync = None
     IsRestricted = False
     OutOfSyncReason = None
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about what exactly your input is, and how you want your output to look?

Comment: Sure. So I want to extract both certificates and key from output above. I want to be able to create 3 files, each containing contents/hash of the respective certificate/key, for example - ( -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEi......U1P8Xh1CDguM+ZEoew==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----) and each of the files would be named Itermediate-cert, Key and Public-cert respectively. For example file containing key hash would be named key.txt and it's content would be what's everything after "Key" word in this output and ending with  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----.

Comment: I am just struggling with regex. Once I have the correct regex expression, I will work out writing to the files myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regular expression: `(-----BEGIN .+?-----(?s).+?-----END .+?-----)`
. You can try it out [here](https://regexr.com/43isr). This works by lazy matching after the begin and after the end, and also lazy matching what is in between.

Comment: Thanks for this. It is almost what I want. Aside from dividing  the hashes I would like to be able to associate word "Key", "Intermediate cert", "Public cert" with it's respective hash.

Comment: Do you mean you want these included in the regular expression? Or are you looking for Python code that will make a variable out of each of them? Or something else?

Comment: I would like the words: "Key", "Intermediate cert", "Public cert" be included in the regex expression so that for example I would like to be able to associate them later with the respective hashes that are under each of these words . The idea is to convert it so that later I will be able to create 3 files each of them will be named: "Key.txt", "Intermediate-cert.txt", "Public-cert.txt" and each of them will contain it's respective cert/key hash.

Comment: Or there can be any other way to associate "Key", "Intermediate cert", "Public cert" words to its respective hashes

Comment: Thanks man, this was exactly what i needed